# Is it possible to use CSS to force update an SCSS code?

Tags: css, sass

I have a template from Codecanyon and it contains compiled SCSS file which I tried to update but it doesn't work. I tried to use CSS to update the section in which the style of the SCSS is affecting but it won't work. I cleared cookies but nothing still. Even the CSS !important doesn't seem to affect the code. Please how can I get this to work?

I also tried to recompile the SCSS code but nothing seem to work

Comment: Is the CSS being added to the website as a link, such as a `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">` ? If so, have you tried adding `?v=1` at the end of the `href` url to set a version number for cache clearing?

Comment: Yes, it is. I will try this and get back to you

Comment: It does not work.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The issue has been resolved, all I did was to change the class name of the element I want to update and add my preferred CSS styling to it. I will appreciate it if anyone can provide a more suitable solution thanks.